# How to push controller after dismiss presented controller in swift?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

Hey I am showing a controller (A) in main controller with presentation style (not push), and I want to button tapped and push another controller (B) after dismiss this (A) controller, this situation occurred in main controller. I am using protocol for this situation. Any idea for that ? Code like below.`

```
//this is dismiss button action

   var segueDelegate: segueFromController?

   @objc func dismissController() {

    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        self.segueDelegate?.segueFromController()
    }

//and this one is protocol function in main controller


    func segueFromController() {

     let contProfile = ContViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

           navigationController?.pushViewController(contProfile, animated: true)

}

// and I am making "self" this protocol in main controller's didload

  let aCont = AController()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            AController.segueDelegate = self
 }

 // protocol

protocol segueFromController { 
  func segueFromController()  
  }

// this is presenting (A) controller code in main page

func openController() {
            let preController = AController()
        preController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.present(preController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing ?

Comment: when I tapped dismiss button it is closing controller and turn in main controller but not push (B) controller

Comment: segueFromController function is calling ?

Comment: no. this is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make this segueDelegate weak

```
protocol segueFromController : class {
func segueFromController()
}
weak var segueDelegate: segueFromController?

func openController() {
            let preController = AController()
         preController.segueDelegate = self
        preController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.present(preController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Try to dismiss without animation

```
self.dismiss(animated: false) {
             self.segueDelegate?.segueFromController()
        }
```

Comment: this give this error: 'weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound 'segueFromController'; consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound

Comment: or share your test project

Comment: how can I share test project. sorry I am new about swift

Comment: wetransfer.com through this site

Comment: I am opening (A Controller) In main page.. added in edit

Comment: check my code... and edit your ... remove ` AController.segueDelegate = self` from didload

Comment: thank you but it doesn't enter segueFromController function in main controller

Comment: Share your project

Comment: How can I share just this part of project ? and for wetransfer.com should I know your e mail ?

Comment: L060214@gmail.com

Comment: thank you very much man. I gave a feedback in here thanks a lot